# python3, UnicodeDecodeError when reading contents of unzipped file

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have some code to download some zipped csv files, unzip them and then concatenate the data into a single dataframe. The problem is that I get the error

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def findZipLinks(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")
    links = [agecaredata_url + a.get('data-link') for a in bs.findAll('a', {"class": "downloadhrefp_lt_WebPartZone6_znMC_pageplaceholder_p_lt_WebPartZone2_ZoneA_znPublicationFooterItem_znPublicationFooterItem_zone_Stacker_MultiColumns u-dtb u-w100p u-bgc-primary u-c-fff c-publication__download u-mb-gutter0p25x"}) if "zip" in a.get("data-link")]
    return links


exits = findZipLinks('https://www.gen-agedcaredata.gov.au/Resources/Access-data/2018/June/GEN-data-People-leaving-aged-care')
dfs = []
for exit_url in exits:
    r = requests.get(exit_url)
    zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[0]), dtype=str))

pd.concat(df for df in dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The problem is that I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 2: invalid start byte` on the append line. I have tried calling .decode('utf-8') and .decode('windows-1252') but I receive similar errors. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: What line are you referring to that gives you the error?

Comment: The error is on `dfs.append(pd.read_csv(zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[0]), dtype=str))`

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file specify the read mode as `wb`

```
zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[0], 'wb')
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error `ValueError: open() requires mode "r" or "w"`. Do I need to add anything else to make this work?